# C# Not sending email SMTP

Tags: c#, email

I've published my website using VS publishing options and IIS on a server. 
In localhost i can send emails but when i publish it i was not able anymore to send it.
This is my code to send email:

```
string toEmail = DBConFactory.getInstance()
    .getPessoaBynOrdem(id).Rows[0]["email"].ToString();

MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
string fromEmail = "gccc.teste@gmail.com";
string fromPW = "xxxxx";
message.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
message.To.Add(toEmail);
message.Subject = "Aprovação GCCC";
message.Body = "Caro(a) Dr(a). " + 
    DBConFactory.getInstance().getPessoaBynOrdem(id).Rows[0]["nome"].ToString() + 
    ", O seu registo no Gestor de Casos Clínicos foi aceite.";
message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail, fromPW);

smtpClient.Send(message.From.ToString(), message.To.ToString(),
    message.Subject, message.Body);
```

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: is it firewall problem? try changing the port to 25 and see

Comment: @JamieMeyer I dont get any error. I just dont receive the email.

Comment: @Steve just tried it and doesnt work

Comment: You need to wrap the smtpClient.Send in a try catch block. You are likely receiving an exception which you are not processing. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc(v=vs.110).aspx